# How to validate multiple object and get the wrong one on selenium java

Tags: java, validation, selenium-webdriver

i need your help to validate mutiple object.
So the test cases is

**Choose item->proceed->proceed->proceed->finish.**

I obtain these price object on each page of purchasing item test cases.

- a=50
- b=50
- c=1
- d=50
- e=50

In this case i need to automate my script to find which one is different. *When the item is changed, value will be changed.*

Because i want to make this for automation testing, i need the script to understand if there's any different value like c, it mean script will print "failed" and "c"(c is object that different then the other.).

```
   String a=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='cart_unit']")).getText;//this is locator for price object
    driver.findelements(By.xpath("//td[@class='proceed']")).click();

    String b=driver.findelEments(By.xpath("//td[@class='cart_unit']")).getText;//this is locator for price object
    driver.findelements(By.xpath("//td[@class='proceed']")).click();

    String c=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='cart_unit']")).getText;//this is locator for price object
    driver.findelements(By.xpath("//td[@class='proceed']")).click();

    String d=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='cart_unit']")).getText;//this is locator for price object
    driver.findelements(By.xpath("//td[@class='proceed']")).click();

    String e=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//td[@class='cart_unit']")).getText;//this is locator for price object
    driver.findelements(By.xpath("//td[@class='proceed']")).click();


//here i need code how to compare them all, and tell the script to write "failed" and "c"(give the object which make it failed,if there's one object that have different value).
```

Comment: How come this question's headline contains "java" and is tagged with "java"? `Int a=driver.findelements(By.xpath("//td[@class='cart_unit']"));` this is **not** Java code.

Comment: Yes, that is selenium code :) i mention it on the title. On the bottom code, there i need the java.
Is it wrong to use java on this question when i need the java code to finish this?

Comment: If that code compiles with your Java compiler - fine. I don't know what you mean by _selenium java_ or _selenium code_. All I want to say is that in the standard Java Selenium API (downloaded from http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/) `findelements` does not exist and `findElements` does not return an `Int` (which again is not a type in standard Java) but a `java.util.List`. If you use some obscure additional 3rd party libs, it should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: I already change the int to String on the code and add .getText.

Comment: @xkid  It would help if you copied the runnable code right out of your IDE and pasted it into the question. That would eliminate issues like Würgspaß is pointing out. There are still typos in the code you have posted right now.

Comment: @JeffC thanks for the input, i will write on my compiler first for my next question. Sorry still newbie here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this. I cleaned up your code a little to simplify it.

Basically each time you scrape a price, it gets added to an `ArrayList`. Once all the prices are scraped, we count the number of unique prices in the list using a `HashSet`. If there is more than one unique price, then you would log a failure and dump all the prices, e.g. `[$50.00, $50.00, $1.00, $50.00, $50.00]`. There are several ways to do this... this is just the one that I chose. You can google and find more.

```
By priceLocator = By.xpath("//td[@class='cart_unit']");
By proceedLocator = By.xpath("//td[@class='proceed']");

List<String> prices = new ArrayList<String>();
prices.add(driver.findElement(priceLocator).getText());
driver.findElement(proceedLocator).click();
prices.add(driver.findElement(priceLocator).getText());
driver.findElement(proceedLocator).click();
prices.add(driver.findElement(priceLocator).getText());
driver.findElement(proceedLocator).click();
prices.add(driver.findElement(priceLocator).getText());
driver.findElement(proceedLocator).click();
prices.add(driver.findElement(priceLocator).getText());
driver.findElement(proceedLocator).click();

Set<String> uniquePrices = new HashSet<String>(prices);
if (uniquePrices.size() > 1)
{
    // log failure
    System.out.println(prices);
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this and tell you the result later.

Comment: Even this is not what exactly what im looking for, this code work when i place it on mine.

Thanks @JeffC.

Comment: You could add additional logic to count the different unique price instances and print the one that has only one instance. I figured this would be just as good but require a lot less code and logic to sort through. In the end, you get to see all the prices and can quickly determine which one is different.